# Working part time beside full time

Tags: contract-law, canada

I am living in Ontario, Canada and I am currently working as full time employee in a large company. But based on my agreement, I am not allowed to work more than 40 hours every week (I do not get paid for it).

I am wondering is it possible to accept a small part time job beside this job?

Comment: If you do it on your own time it should be fine. However if you have signed a contract with the large company they may preclude you working for other companies while you work with them. Do you know if there is a clause in your contract prohibiting such work?

Comment: I am not sure, I have to check my contract. But, lets assume that the company is fine with it, then, is it possible to have a part time contract beside a full time contract and get paid for both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can work as many jobs as you can cope with.

Your employer (any of them) can only interfere if:

1. It affects your performance,
2. Your other job infringes on their business e.g. your second job is in competition with the first. So working for 2 software houses is no good but if your second job is as a bartender, that would be fine.

This is the case even absent a specific clause in your contract. Further, any clause that purported to go further would be unenforceable as an unfair restraint of trade.

Comment: How about a kindergarten teacher moonlighting as a lap-dancer?  I don't see that as either #1, or #2, but the school board would certainly object...

Comment: @DJohnM #1 certainly applies - part of a teacher's job is to serve as a role model.

Comment: Yes;  especially if a father picking up his five-year old recognizes/is recognized from the previous evening...